# Imported Variable not defined

Tags: python-3.x, python-import

Currently trying to import my code from "Original Program" which is working fine independently into "Import". I am getting the error "Date is not defined". I assume the error is to do with global variables. I am knew to this and have spent some time trying to solve the issue myself to no avail. Any help appreciated :)

```
 **Original Program**   

def validDate(date, month, day):
    months = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
    days = [31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31]
    leapyear = ((date % 4) == 0) and ((date % 100) != 0) or ((date % 4) == 
    0) and ((date % 100) == 0) and ((date % 4000) == 0)
    if leapyear:
    days[1] += 1 
    valid = (day <= days[months.index(month)] and day > 0 and (1753 <= 
    date)) 
    print(valid)

date = int(input("Enter year: "))
month = int(input("Enter month: "))
day = int(input("Enter day: "))

validDate(date, month, day)


**Import**

from libHWDate import validDate

validDate(date, month, day)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

remove the import command
from libHWDate import validDate